# Why HHVM and NGINX are used together?

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I thought HHVM can already serve the website. Why do we need NGINX?

I used to install mediawiki on just Apache and MySQL and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX is used as a reverse proxy with HHVM. Depending on what you're doing with it, HHVM might be a better processor for PHP than letting NGINX deal with PHP on its own. I'm not in a position to say which solution is best, only that those options exist.